# Writing data from one CSV file to another CSV file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

I have a CSV file with two rows of data. The first row are the names like Red, Green, Orange, Purple and they repeat themselves like that. The second row is the data. The format is how I have written below, but in a CSV file. I want to take this and put them in separate columns like I have shown in table 2 but again in a CSV file. How do I combine the similar names and keep the data for it all? I understand I could write them out like this

```
lista1=["Red", "Green", "Orange", "Purple"] 
lista2=[3,56,23,12,34,65,98,7,9,45,33,15]
```

and call on them although I have 100's of files like this and I can't change the numbers and titles each time

Table 1:

| Red | Green | Orange | Purple | Red | Green | Orange | Purple | Red | Green | Orange | Purple |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 56 | 23 | 12 | 34 | 65 | 98 | 7 | 9 | 45 | 33 | 15 |

Table 2 (output):

| Red | Green | Orange | Purple |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 56 | 23 | 12 |
| 34 | 65 | 98 | 7 |
| 9 | 45 | 33 | 15 |

Again the table 1 data is from CSV file and I want the desired output in a CSV file as well.

Comment: I'm a little confused what output you're trying to get. So you want the colors combined (so each is only listed once), but not the numbers (or do you, and you just happen to not have any duplicates in this sample?). And then it all printed on one line?

Comment: Yea I just want the colors combine so each is listed just once but not the numbers.

Comment: What's the deal with the dashes? Will all the files have those between the words and the number? and do you need to keep the same number of them? (You have less in Table 2 than in Table1.)

Comment: Sorry its suppose to be a formatted table but its not working so I added a picture instead

Comment: Oh, yeah, that makes a lot more sense. You can do this with Pandas, I'll see if I can get you some code.

Comment: Is there any way I can do it with a csv module? Pandas doesnt seem to work on 3.9.6 for me and thats the version I have to use

Comment: Sorry, I wouldn't have any idea how to do it with the csv module. The way I would do it is read in the .csv, use some regex to make a list of the words and list of the numbers, put them in a dataframe, transform it to group it by words, then do df.to_csv

Comment: I do know that method as I mentioned above in the question but I have 100's of files and data and I want to automate the data frame instead of writing list of words each time

Comment: You are basically asking how to group two lists by the values in the first list. The fact that these come from and will be written to CSV is only tangential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, you do not need `pandas` in your solution, here is one that only uses `csv` module.

I read the file using `csv.reader()` function. Converted the data into dictionary according to the sample input csv file you provided and then converted that dictionary into csv file.

Here is the sample csv input file :-

> ```
> Red,Green,Orange,Purple,Red,Green,Orange,Purple,Red,Green,Orange,Purple
> 3,56,23,12,34,65,98,7,9,45,33,15
> ```

Now the code:-

```
import csv
with open('try.csv') as csvfile:
    mixedData = csv.reader(csvfile)
    column,data = mixedData
    
data_dict = {}
for i,name in enumerate(column) :
    if name in data_dict :
        data_dict[name].append(data[i])
    else :
        data_dict[name] = [data[i]]
        

with open("try_output.csv", "w",newline="") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(data_dict.keys())
    writer.writerows(zip(*data_dict.values()))
```

output file :-

> ```
> Red,Green,Orange,Purple
> 3,56,23,12
> 34,65,98,7
> 9,45,33,15
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. This assumes that the first row is always going to be words of some kind, and the bottom will always be numbers. As long as that's true, you don't need to know what the words are ahead of time.

First, read the data from the csv file. (I'm not reading it directly into a dataframe because column names need to be unique.)

```python
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import re

>>> infile = '/path/to/sample.csv'
>>> f = open(infile, 'r')
>>> text = f.read()
>>> print(text)

Red,Green,Orange,Purple,Red,Green,Orange,Purple,Red,Green,Orange,Purple
3,56,23,12,34,65,98,7,9,45,33,15
```

Then separate out your words and numbers, using regex:

```python
>>> words = re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", text)
>>> numbers = re.findall("[0-9]+", text)
>>> print(words)
>>> print(numbers)
```

Create your dataframe:

```python
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...     "Words": words,
...     "Numbers": numbers
... })

>>> print(df)

     Words Numbers
0      Red       3
1    Green      56
2   Orange      23
3   Purple      12
4      Red      34
5    Green      65
6   Orange      98
7   Purple       7
8      Red       9
9    Green      45
10  Orange      33
11  Purple      15
```

Group the words together. (This seems like a convoluted way of doing it, but I couldn't figure out a simpler one.)

```python
>>> words_no_repeats = list(set(words))
>>> new_df = pd.DataFrame()
>>> for w in words_no_repeats:
...     values = df[df['Words']==w]['Numbers'].to_list()
...     temp_df = pd.DataFrame({w: values}, index=range(len(values)))
...     new_df = pd.concat([new_df, temp_df], axis=1)    

print(new_df)

  Orange Green Red Purple
0     23    56   3     12
1     98    65  34      7
2     33    45   9     15
```

Then save your new dataframe as a csv:

```python
>>> new_df.to_csv('/path/to/new_sample.csv', index=False)
```

This is what the csv file looks like:

```
Orange,Green,Red,Purple
23,56,3,12
98,65,34,7
33,45,9,15
```

I know you said in your comments that you were trying to avoid Pandas, but I don't know of any other way to do the grouping.